# properly importing node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am newbie learning NodeJS and getting error message **module not found** Please help me try to find the reason.

**app.js**

```
const getNotes = require('./notes.js')
const msg = getNotes();
console.log(msg)
```

**notes.js**

```
const getNotes= function (){

    return 'My notes are publishing'
}
module.exports = getNotes
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code - it should work perfectly. You've not told us how you are invoking `app.js` nor have you shared the folder structure.

Comment: check your file path on your require statement. Where your current line `'./notes.js'` implies that notes is in the same directory as app.js.

Comment: What is the folder structure of the files and how are you launching node?

Comment: Both files are in same folder and launching the code by writing command `node app.js` in terminal.